# StdRandom, StdOut, Insertion cannot be resolved

Tags: java, sorting, input

This code should implement sorting.
I have 3 errors:
"StdRandom cannot be resolved",
"StdOut cannot be resolved",
"Insertion cannot be resolved".
May be there are some libraries to import?

```
public class randomDoubles 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    Double[] a = new Double[N];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        a[i] = StdRandom.uniform(); // error: StdRandom cannot be resolved
    Insertion.sort(a);                  // error: Insertion cannot be resolved
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        StdOut.println(a[i]);       // error: StdOut cannot be resolved
}
}
```

Comment: You should use `System.out.println()` for printing.. not `StdOut.println`.. And where is your `Insertion` class?? and why are you using `StdRandom` for??

Comment: If you are in eclipse, hit command-shift-o (ctrl-shift-o on windows) to have it do a best-guess of what you need to import.

Comment: this is not my code, i'm trying to get the example of sorting. and it soppose to sort random numbers and print them into command line,, so as i understand, there is no java library to implement sorting?

Comment: coursera.com algorithms course

Answer (score 4):

you need to use the following files

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdRandom.java.html

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/StdOut.java.html

Comment: And how do you import them?

Comment: Just create new files with these contents with names of the classes in the same folder with main file, and it will definitely run.

Comment: If you are using DrJava, you can include stdlib.jar in the classpath,  Preferences -> Extra Classpath -> Add. Check http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely missing some imports of non-standard libraries here.  If you want to compile and use this code as it is, you should ask your professor where to find the libraries and how to import them.

But if you just want an example of doing approximately what's shown here with standard java libraries, the following might suffice:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomDoubles {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        Double[] a = new Double[N];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            a[i] = rand.nextDouble();
        Arrays.sort(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            System.out.println(a[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can download jar from site below
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/, and import it to your project

Answer (score 0):

The link offered by others didn't handle idea. If you are idea(jetbrains intellij idea) user, you also need go to File->Project Structure->Libraries and add algs4.jar

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue years ago when I took the same class, the issue here is that `StdRabdom` and `StdOut` are all third party libraries written by the course authors. The only way to solve this issue is by installing libraries to your local machine like rv1822 mentioned. The installation instructions are also included in the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

From the course codes add the external libraries with

File->Project Structure->Libraries and add algs4.jar

import the following
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;